# batch file /wait not working, where did I do wrong?

Tags: python, batch-file

```
@echo off
cd ..
start /WAIT /B "" "python" appcfg.py update src1/
echo "finished!"
pause
```

The "finished" is printed out before my start command is finished.

Where did I do wrong?

Also which one is correct, they seem to have the same effect

```
start /WAIT /B "" "python" appcfg.py update src1/
start "" /WAIT /B  "python" appcfg.py update src1/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just run it as `python appcfg.py update src1/` or swap `/wait`, `/b`?

Comment: With start the trick is the first set of quotes, no matter where they are, are assumed to be the window title. Your start command is using shellexecute but achieves exactly the same as if you hadn't used start. In a batchfile, unlike when typing, programs always wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this - it should execute one line at a time.

```
@echo off
cd ..
"python" appcfg.py update src1/
echo "finished!"
pause
```